# java heap space

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

do you have any idea why I could get a **'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space'** error when building my android app, even though I added -vmargs -Xmx1024M -Xms512M to the eclipse arguments ?
I would like to know what error could I have made that would trigger such an error at build time, as it would appear to me that only a bug in eclipse or maven could produce such an error at build time.
I am using run as maven install to build my application (with the maven android eclipse plugin). Run as-> 'maven package' also produces the same build failure, after waiting roughly 1min30.
I have a desktop computer with 3GB of memory, and my application isn't nearly that big.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any bitmap functions in your app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/some/path` to your jvm args so that when it runs out of memory it will dump out the heap. You can then use [Eclipse Memory Analyser](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) or [`jhat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) to browse the heap and diagnose where the problem might be.

**Update**: Try increasing the memory of your maven android plugin. In your `pom.xml`, add a JVM argument for `Xmx` to the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <jvmArguments>
      <argument>-Xmx1500m</argument>
    </jvmArguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't manage to dump the heap. Are these arguments supposed to be inserted in the same location as the 'VM arguments' text box of the 'run configuration' in eclipse, like this: -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="C:" ?

Comment: oh my god thank you so much ! I've been trying to fix this for days. Could I have a short explanation as to why this works, why is it that they use separate jvms and why do the arguments of the calling process (eclipse, jre, ...) aren't automatically set to the child process ?

Comment: It would not make much sense to propagate those settings to 'child' processes. Why? They do not share the memory, each vm has its own memory. Eclipse might need 768m, Maven 256m and the android plugin 1024m. So it would be pretty desctructive just to set the maximim heap everywhere. How should Java know it should only use a 10th?

Comment: I have to add: To me it sounds strange that would would so much memory for an Android app. The Tipp of @dogbane to start investigating why you need so much memory is much more relevant than the insight that you just need more

Comment: Where can I find the pom.xml file?

Comment: this file does not exist in the project directory. Please point out where it is supposed to be... @dogbane

Answer (score 2):

Your Eclipse JVM arguments do not matter. You have to increase the heap of the compiler.

I am quoting http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/fix-javac-java-lang-outofmemoryerror.html

> If [...] you're running Eclipse, go into your "run As" dialog for your Build.xml and add -Xms256m -Xmx256m to the "VM Arguments" text box

Comment: This was so clever that for a while a really thought it would solve my issue. I didn't know the JVM of eclipse was different than that of the compiler. So just so we are clear, what I did was to click on the run arrow, then run configurations, then select my run configuration, then go to the JRE tab, and in the 'VM arguments' blank textbox, add '-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M', then apply and run.
This unfortunately didn't work, the issue is still the same.

Comment: Yeah, because, I do now realize that you are using the Android plugin of Maven and its Eclipse integration. That means that Eclipse compiler settings do not matter, but that of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space. increasing the all of the values in the eclipse.ini file didn't help. This happened to me after I upgraded my ADT plugin from 12 to 16. I changed the Android SDKs that were pointed to my existing projects prior to the upgrade (from the android sdks that were connected on my previous adt I changed them to the android sdks that were connected to my new adt) and it solved the issue for me. hope this helps. and if it helps someone please vote for plus 1 this.

Answer (score 0):

If increasing does not respond then I would suggest to you that check the line count for each class you wrote. It can be a compiler problem if there are a lot of objects so try to partitioning methods and/or copy them into new classes if one or more of the classes have 3000+ lines.