# Running a Robolectric test from IntelliJ causes OutOfMemory

Tags: android, intellij-idea, robolectric

I am trying to run a unit test from IntelliJ that uses Robolectric by following the example here ::
http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/intellij-quick-start.html

Have added the Robolectric jar and a jar for Junit4. When the test runs I see the following output >>

[image: IntelliJ Output]

Have googled around and found some suggestions that I need to specify some vm args. This post is describing a similar issue with Eclipse [java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075875/java-heap-space) The post is concerned with using Robolectric in tandem with a Maven project. I have read that it is easier to use Robolectric inside a Maven project but I have elected not to do this as my Android project has no other use for Maven.

If anyone has any wisdom on what is wrong here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it happen on compilation or when running? Did you try to adjust the heap for compiler and in the run configuration?

Comment: Did you try to adjust [this setting](http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/2369/20121122001237.png)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help. You need proper local.properties file with android sdk location in the root of your project to run Robolectric correctly:

```
sdk-location=c:\\Development\\android-sdk-windows
sdk.dir=c:\\Development\\android-sdk-windows
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found an answer here: https://coderwall.com/p/rcgyfq

```
1.- Copy the file "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/bin/idea.vmoptions" to "~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/idea.vmoptions"
2.- Edit file "~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/idea.vmoptions"
3.- For example change -Xmx800m by -Xmx2048m
4.- Restart IntellijIDEA 12
```

This stopped my Out of Memory exceptions and greatly decreased my overall test time.